# how to take all the files with `.flg` Extension and put the numbers on a list

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

i have files in c:\MyData for example:

```
demo.txt
test.ini
COUNT030.flg
COUNT011.flg
COUNT020.flg
COUNT031.flg
COUNT045.flg
COUNT067.flg
```

i need to take all the files with `.flg` Extension and to put the numbers on list like this:

```
30
11
20
31
45
67
```

how to do this in C# WinForm ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as promised the sample:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp\");
FileInfo[] fis = di.GetFiles("*.flg");
foreach (FileInfo fi in fis)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0}, Full Name: {1}, Number: {2}", fi.Name, fi.FullName, fi.Name.Substring(fi.Name.LastIndexOf(".") - 3, 3));
}
```

for extracting the numbers look at the Substring in the sample.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx) or `Directory.GetFiles` method and mask `*.flg`. Then use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to extract file-name without extension, then apply regex `\d+$` to match number.

Example:

```
var result = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(path, "*.flg")
    .Select(s => int.Parse(Regex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s), @"\d+$").Value));
```

Comment: +1 for actually providing a solution that doesn't require the filenames to have the exact same format.

Comment: Nice solution, upvoted. @J. Steen: it still won't work with ("COUNT0AT30.flg", "COUNT0AT31.flg", ...) type of sequence.

Comment: @Grozz , You mean your solution?

Comment: @Grozz, Never said it would. =)

Comment: @polishchuk, neither of solutions on this page. it's only possible to loosen up the format to a certain degree of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        var numbers = from fileInfo in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.flg")
                      let fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name)
                      select int.Parse(fileName.Substring("Count".Length, 3));

        List<int> lst = numbers.ToList();
```

Comment: works only if the filename has ALWAYS the same length

Comment: No, it works if the filename has the same "layout" (i.e. "Count" + 3 digits), not length.

Comment: ok, after rereading i saw it ...